# Access arbitrary helper from within a view in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, helper

Let's say I'm in some view and I want to access a method in some unrelated helper:

```
<?= $this->otherHelper->doSomething() ?>
```

How would I actually do this? And, can I have my method be named differently than the last part of my class (Zend_View_Helper_OtherHelper)?

Answer (score 4):

If your helper extends `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract` and is in the same module, then you can just call `$this->view->otherHelper()`.

If it's in a different module, then you might need to specify some some additional helper paths on the `$view`.

If you want to use an alternate method for the call, you could just instantiate the `OtherHelper` class directly and call the alternate method. But in that case, the views's registered helper paths won't help you with the autoloading, so you'll have to make sure that your autoloader is configured with the right namespaces and prefix/path maps.

**UPDATE**

On re-reading your question, some additional thoughts on calling additional methods on a view helper.

If you are writing the other view helper yourself - as opposed to simply using one that is already written - you can use a structure in which the direct call returns a reference to itself. Then you can use a fluent interface call various methods on the same helper. Something like this:

```
class My_View_Helper_GreetMe extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected $_name;

    public function greetMe($name)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function withCompliment()
    {
        return sprintf('Hi, %s. You look great today!', $this->_name);
    }

    public function withPutDown()
    {
        return sprintf('Hey, %s, you look like hell. Drunk again, are you?', $this->_name);
    }

    // The default representation of the greeting. Let's be nice, by default.
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->withCompliment();
    }
}
```

Then usage could be:

```
$view->greetMe('David')->withCompliment();
```